# Concatenate unlimited amount of arrays with predefined function

Tags: java, array

I am working on learning more about arrays and loops! I have been trying to create a method which will allow me to take for example an unlimited amount of arrays and append or concatenate them to each other!

The method takes multiple arrays as arguments and creates a merged array in the order in which the arrays where passed through the parameter. My question is:

Is there a more efficient way to do this which I am maybe not aware of?

I have done my research but most ways usually use a set amount of arrays in order to achieve this. This is just something I am doing for the sake of learning, and these functions may not be useful in real life scenarios.

```
public static Object[] merge(Object[]... arrays) {
    int[] lenghts = new int[arrays.length];
    int wholeLenght = 0;
    int maxLenght = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<arrays.length; i++){
        lenghts[i] = arrays[i].length;          
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<lenghts.length; i++){
        wholeLenght += lenghts[i];
    }
    Object[] merged  = new Object[wholeLenght];

    for(int i = 0; i<arrays.length; i++){
        System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, merged, maxLenght, lenghts[i]);
        maxLenght+=lenghts[i];
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Version which allows generic types. A similar function can be easily made for 
primitive a primitive type array of choice.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] mergeGenerics(T[]... arrays) {
    int[] lenghts = new int[arrays.length];
    boolean allowOperation = true;
    int wholeLenght = 0;
    int maxLenght = 0;
    T[] merged = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        if (arrays[0].getClass().getComponentType() != arrays[i].getClass().getComponentType()) {
            allowOperation = false;
            System.err.println("The arrays are not all of the same type!!");
        }
    }
    if (allowOperation) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            lenghts[i] = arrays[i].length;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lenghts.length; i++) {
            wholeLenght += lenghts[i];
        }
        merged = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arrays[0].getClass().getComponentType(), wholeLenght);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, merged, maxLenght, lenghts[i]);
            maxLenght += lenghts[i];
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Test The method maybe with:

```
        Object[] obj1 ={"A","B"};
        Object[] obj2 ={"C","D","E","F"};
        Object[] obj3 ={"G","H","I","J","K"};
        Object[] obj4 ={"L","M","N"};
        String[] obj5 ={"O","P","Q","R"};
        Object[] obj6 ={"S"};
        Object[] merge = Class.merge(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5,obj6);

        for(int i = 0; i<merge.length; i++)
            System.out.print(merge[i]+" ");
```

Comment: By efficient, what do you mean exactly? Less code? Faster execution performance?

Comment: @RomanVottner Yes faster execution and most importantly i want to know if there are alternative ways to do this, meaning if their are functions in java which I don't know of which already do the same as my code. alternative ways to do this =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach suggested by @Caridorc has the limitation that it requires the objects passed to be `Iterable`s, which an array is not a subtype of [due to certain limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable). Therefore, you either have to change your data type from an array to some `Iterable` extension or use a different approach.

A simple, naive solution would be to simple convert arrays to `List`s and add all to a combined list like this:

```
private static <T> T[] merge2(T[] ... arrays) {
    final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
      list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    }
    return list.toArray(arrays[0]);
}
```

which has certain runtime penalties as you create multiple new objects which furthermore on adding new lists via `addAll(...)` will increase the capacity of the list by 50% of its current length on exceeding the current size and therefore contain some unused space.

A further approach is based on your generic approach but contains only two loops. The first one to learn the total length, the second one to copy the data from the source array to the target array:

```
private static <T> T[] merge3(T[] ... arrays) {
    Class<?> componentType = arrays[0].getClass().getComponentType();
    int size = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
      size += array.length;
    }
    T[] result = (T[])arrays[0].getClass().cast(Array.newInstance(componentType, size));
    int pos = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
      System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, pos, array.length);
      pos += array.length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This method is shorter and IMO easier to read then your implementation. A short comparison between the 4 algorithms reveals also, that it is faster then the other ones:

```
Original - Total: 51.402688 ms, Average: 5.1402688E-4 ms
Original Generics - Total: 42.150794 ms, Average: 4.2150794E-4 ms
Merge2 - Total: 87.06185 ms, Average: 8.706185E-4 ms
Merge3 - Total: 28.701731 ms, Average: 2.8701731E-4 ms
```

Note however, that I did a naive performance test and didn't take care of compiler optimizations or warm-up phases. The comparison therefore may be flawed and data messy.

Also note that I did not take care of checking if all of the passed arrays are of the same type. Mingling multiple arrays of different types might only work if the first passed array is of type object (or at least a supertype of any further arrays). In general, I wouldn't allow to pass arrays of different types though.

BTW: the double cast in `merge3` is to get rid of `Unchecked cast` warnings

Comment: This is indeed very informative!  thank you very much for your complete answer. The speed of merge three is fantastic. I look more into these examples.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that arrays or lists are sub-optimal for this task as the result will be given only after the processing of the last array is finished (time overhead) and the whole result array has to be stored in memory (space overhead).

Iterables do not store new values and yield from the iterables as soon as possible, so I suggest that you use them as data structure.

[A standard implementation already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection) so you may compare it to what you come up with to enhance the learning experience.

Comment: That is definitely what I was trying to achieve. Thank you very much for the helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

#### Spelling

`Length` is (surprisingly consistently) misspelled as `lenght`, it's highly recommended to fix this mistake. :)

#### Stream-based processing

You can take advantage of the `Stream` semantics in Java 8 to express the steps in another way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] merge(T[]... arrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(arrays)
                    // MAGIC HERE
                    .toArray(x -> (T[]) Array.newInstance(
                            arrays.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType(), x));
}
```

1. Use [`Arrays.stream(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) to convert the array of `T[]` arrays to a `Stream<T[]>` stream.
2. `MAGIC HERE`... will be explained below, essentially we need to convert `Stream<T[]>` to just `Stream<T>`.
3. Use the reflection-based [`Array.newInstance(Class, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-) method to create our generic array. `getComponentType()` is called twice, as the first time only gives us `Class<T[]>`, and the second call on that will return `Class<T>`.

There's two possible approaches for `MAGIC HERE`.

1. A single [`reduce(U, BiFunction, BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) step to reduce all the `T[]` stream elements into just `Stream<T>`:

   ```
   .reduce(Stream.empty(),
           (s, a) -> a == null ? s : Stream.concat(s, Arrays.stream(a)),
           Stream::concat)
   ```

   `Stream.empty()` is our starting point, and I've chosen to specially handle the case where a `T[]` array might be `null` by skipping over it. To combine two `Stream` pipelines together, [`Stream.concat(Stream, Stream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) is used as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as the final step.
2. Requires two steps, but each step is arguably simpler to digest, and overall performance is much faster too:

   ```
   .map(a -> a == null ? Stream.empty() : Arrays.stream(a))
   .flatMap(Function.identity())
   ```

   The first step also takes care of a `null` array, by treating it as an empty stream. The second step [replaces each `Stream<T>` element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) with [its contents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) on a resulting `Stream<T>`.

Using the second approach as the foundation, you can attempt to parallelize the process by adding the [`Stream.parallel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--), and if you are OK to drop the `null`-handling, a tweaked solution can be just:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] merge(T[]... arrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(arrays)
                    .parallel()
                    .map(Arrays::stream)
                    .flatMap(Function.identity())
                    .toArray(x -> (T[]) Array.newInstance(
                            arrays.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType(), x));
}
```